# How can I convert the following JSON string to Java Object by Gson?

Tags: java, android, database, json, gson

I am having a problem to convert this json string to java object now. I have tried many ways, what I have got so far either errors like **"Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 44"** I know the problem is from here ***\"errmsg\":*** in the string i made. Or errors like **"Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 49"**, if I delete the errmsg part of my string. While i was trying, i made it run several times, but all the values I got either null or 0's, and it didn't even go into class Products.

One additional question: how to write a website link to a string, I always got errors on this part, that's why I comment out those links in the string I made.

**Thank you !**

Here is my json:

```
{"data":{"results":4,"returned":1,"errmsg":""},"products":
       [{"name":"aaa", "region":"USA > CA","price":"1,231.00","year":"2011",
       "link":"http:\/\/www.aaa.com\/abc\/sss-ttt-2011\/",
       "image":"http:\/\/pic.aaa.com\/media\/8\/aaa_12_abc.jpeg"}, 
       {"name":"bbb","region":"USA > WA","price":"31.00","year":"2012",
       "link":"http:\/\/www.bbb.com\/abc\/sss-ttt-2012\/",
       "image":"http:\/\/pic.bbb.com\/media\/7\/bbb_12_abc.jpeg"}]}
```

This is what I have done:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class product {
static String jsonInput = "{" + 
          "\"data\":" + 
          "{\"results\":4,\"returned\":2,\"errmsg\":}," + 
          "\"products\":" +
          "[" +
            "{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"region\":\"USA > CA\",\"price\":1,231.00,\"year\":2011,"+
            //\"link\":\"http:\/\/www.aaa.com\/abc\/sss-ttt-2011\/\", +
            //\"image\":\"http:\/\/pic.aaa.com\/media\/8\/aaa_12_abc.jpeg\" +
            "{\"name\":\"bbb\",\"region\":\"USA > WA\",\"price\":31.00,\"year\":2012,"+
            //\"link\":\"http:\/\/www.bbb.com\/abc\/sss-ttt-2012\/\", +
            //\"image\":\"http:\/\/pic.bbb.com\/media\/8\/bbb_12_abc.jpeg\" +
             "}"+
          "]" +     
         "}";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, Data.class);
    System.out.println(data);
}
}

class Data {

private int results;
private int returned;
private String errmsg;

private Products products;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "[data: results=%1$d, returned=%2$d, errmsg=%3$s, products=%4$s]", 
            results, returned, errmsg, products);
}
}

class Products {
private Products_info[] products_info;

@Override
public String toString() {
return String.format("[%1$s]", Arrays.toString(products_info));
}
}

class Products_info {

private String name;
private String region;
private double price;
private int year;
//private String link;
//private String image;

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "[name=" + name + ", region=" + region + ", price=" + price +
           ", year=" + year +
           //", link=" + link +
           //", image=" + image +           
           "]";
}   
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Change this `"{\"results\":4,\"returned\":2,\"errmsg\":},"` to this `"{\"results\":4,\"returned\":2,\"errmsg\":\"\"},"` to make valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your String may be malformed, but as far as I can tell, the java objects you have defined doesn't translate into the JSON data at all.

This JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "results": 4,
        "returned": 1,
        "errmsg": ""
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "aaa",
            "region": "USA > CA",
            "price": "1,231.00",
            "year": "2011",
            "link": "http://www.aaa.com/abc/sss-ttt-2011/",
            "image": "http://pic.aaa.com/media/8/aaa_12_abc.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "name": "bbb",
            "region": "USA > WA",
            "price": "31.00",
            "year": "2012",
            "link": "http://www.bbb.com/abc/sss-ttt-2012/",
            "image": "http://pic.bbb.com/media/7/bbb_12_abc.jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Should translate into the following objects:

```
SomeObject {
    public class Data {
        private int results;
        private int returned;
        private String errmsg;
    }

    public class Product {
        private String name;
        private String regsion;
        private String price;
        private String year;
        private String link;
        private String image;
    }

    private Data data;
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

Worth noting is that there are numerous online formatters that can escape strings properly so you don't have to do it by hand:

- http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output
- http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html

Comment: also 

`static String jsonInput = "{" + 
          "\"data\":" + 
          "{\"results\":4,\"returned\":2,\"errmsg\":},"`

should be changed to 

`static String jsonInput = "{" + 
          "\"data\":" + 
          "{\"results\":4,\"returned\":2,\"errmsg\":\"\"},"`

And i have already provided the solution for the exact same thing here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746613/how-to-convert-this-json-string-to-java-object-by-gson/16746696#16746696

Comment: Thank you, Could you tell me where I should add my return?

Comment: I've added links to some online string escape tools so you don't have to do it by hand. What do you mean by "where I should add my return"?

Comment: Thx, britzl. If you see my original code, the last 3 classes all have "override" part to print out the formatted java object I want, where should I apply it to the code you wrote here?

Comment: Why would you print out formatted JSON in your toString()? You can convert your objects back to JSON using Gson.toJson(): http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object) There's no need to write any of that yourself.

Comment: because I want to see if I can convert to Java object correctly, and I will use those values later.